# Creating an Ad-Hoc network between two laptops on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I want to create an Ad-Hoc network between two laptops on Windows 7. I do that but it keeps disconnecting. What is the reason ?

Can you give me a guide me to a good tutorial for creating ad-hoc networks ?

Answer (score 2):

For ad-hoc networks and direct Ethernet connections I've found it necessary to set the IP address, Subnet Mask, and most importantly, the Default Gateway for both computers.

The Default Gateway should be set to the IP address of the other computer in the ad-hoc network.

Computer 1
IP Address: 192.168.0.1
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway: 192.168.0.2

Computer 2
IP Address: 192.168.0.2
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway: 192.168.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity, what will you be using the network for? If you want to share an internet connection, [Connectify](http://www.connectify.me/) might work better. It uses the Windows 7 wifi driver framework to set up a virtual access point using the wireless card, which means that other computers connecting see a regular AP, instead of an ad-hoc network. This can reduce problems if you just want to share an internet connection.